# Hugo with Asciidoctor

Tags: blogs, hugo, asciidoctor

I'm trying to setup a blog with Hugo which basically works fine as long as I use Markdown. But since I also have some other website contents (docs) with antora in the repo I want to write all my texts with asciidoc. But I always run into this error, when I try to generate the website from adoc files. Markdown works, but Asciidoc gives this exception:

```
sebastian@kobol:~/work/repos/sommerfeld-io/website/blog$ hugo
Start building sites … 
hugo v0.92.1-85E2E862 linux/amd64 BuildDate=2022-01-27T11:44:41Z VendorInfo=gohugoio
Error: Error building site: "/home/sebastian/work/repos/sommerfeld-io/website/blog/content/posts/my-second-post.adoc:1:1": access denied: "asciidoctor" is not whitelisted in policy "security.exec.allow"; the current security configuration is:

[security]
  enableInlineShortcodes = false
  [security.exec]
    allow = ['^dart-sass-embedded$', '^go$', '^npx$', '^postcss$']
    osEnv = ['(?i)^(PATH|PATHEXT|APPDATA|TMP|TEMP|TERM)$']

  [security.funcs]
    getenv = ['^HUGO_']

  [security.http]
    methods = ['(?i)GET|POST']
    urls = ['.*']


Total in 40 ms
```

Can anyone give me a hint on how I can allow access to asciidoctor from hugo builds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the default [Security Policy](https://gohugo.io/about/security-model/#security-policy). You need to edit your `config.toml` file (or wherever you put your Hugo configuration files) and add a custom security policy.

As a minimum, the custom security policy will be a "cut & paste" of the default, with one or two additional regular expressions added.

For example:

```
[security]
enableInlineShortcodes = false

[security.exec]
allow = ["^dart-sass-embedded$", "^go$", "^npx$", "^postcss$", "^asciidoctor$"]
osEnv = ["(?i)^(PATH|PATHEXT|APPDATA|TMP|TEMP|TERM|RUBYLIB)$"]

[security.funcs]
getenv = ["^HUGO_"]

[security.http]
methods = ["(?i)GET|POST"]
urls = [".*"]
```

I also added the `RUBYLIB` environment variable to tell Hugo to tell AsciiDoctor where its [inline macro extensions](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor/latest/extensions/inline-macro-processor/) live.

Comment: indeed ... I added "^asciidoctor$" to the allowed extensions and it worked