# Hugo with asciidoctor broken "can't find gem asciidoctor"

Tags: ruby, hugo, asciidoctor

I have an existing blog with Hugo and Asciidoctor, but running `hugo server` started failing. I first added the additional security configuration as explained in [Hugo with Asciidoctor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71058236/hugo-with-asciidoctor).

But things are still not working, I get this error:

```
ERROR 2022/02/19 17:11:36 blog/2021/12/23/Taming Thymeleaf 2.0 release.adoc: /Users/wdb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:277:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem asciidoctor (>= 0.a) with executable asciidoctor (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
ERROR 2022/02/19 17:11:36 blog/2021/12/23/Taming Thymeleaf 2.0 release.adoc: from /Users/wdb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:296:in `activate_bin_path'
ERROR 2022/02/19 17:11:36 blog/2021/12/23/Taming Thymeleaf 2.0 release.adoc: from /Users/wdb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/asciidoctor:23:in `<main>'
ERROR 2022/02/19 17:11:36 blog/2021/12/23/Taming Thymeleaf 2.0 release.adoc: from /Users/wdb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
ERROR 2022/02/19 17:11:36 blog/2021/12/23/Taming Thymeleaf 2.0 release.adoc: from /Users/wdb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
ERROR 2022/02/19 17:11:36 asciidoctor rendering blog/2021/12/23/Taming Thymeleaf 2.0 release.adoc: failed to execute binary "asciidoctor" with args [--no-header-footer -]: /Users/wdb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:277:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem asciidoctor (>= 0.a) with executable asciidoctor (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /Users/wdb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:296:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /Users/wdb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/asciidoctor:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/wdb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    from /Users/wdb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

I am using:

- Hugo: `hugo v0.92.0+extended darwin/amd64 BuildDate=unknown`
- Ruby: `ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-darwin19]`
- Bundler: `Bundler version 2.1.4`

I have a `Gemfile` like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'asciidoctor'
gem 'rouge'
```

with `Gemfile.lock`:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    asciidoctor (2.0.17)
    rouge (3.28.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  asciidoctor
  rouge

BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

Let me know if you need anything else to help me debug this.

UPDATE:

I ran `rvm install ruby 2.7.5` to install Ruby 2.7.5 and now I get this error running `hugo server`:

```
WARN 2022/02/20 10:47:43 blog/2021/12/23/Taming Thymeleaf 2.0 release.adoc: Ignoring ffi-1.11.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.11.3
```

I ran `gem install ffi --version='1.11.3'` and `gem pristine ffi --version 1.11.3`, but still the same error message.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to make it work again by removing RVM completely from my system using the commands in https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is an expected behavior. [Starting](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commit/f4389e48ce0a70807362772d66c12ab5cd9e15f8) from the version 0.91 Hugo [filters out](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/ed9aa374dd5e18fbfb207a0a10cde2362061c8ca/common/hexec/exec.go#L92-L94) the environment for child processes [according](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/ed9aa374dd5e18fbfb207a0a10cde2362061c8ca/config/security/securityConfig.go#L45) to some regex. So the issue is simple: `GEM_PATH` (or `GEM_HOME`) is filtered out. Read more in [this ticket](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/9741).

To fix it simply whitelist the `GEM_PATH` variable in your `config.yaml` (`config.toml`):

```yaml
security:
  exec:
    osEnv:
      - (?i)^(PATH|PATHEXT|APPDATA|TMP|TEMP|TERM|GEM_PATH)$ # Note this GEM_PATH
    allow:
      - asciidoctor                                         # Don't forget to whitelist Asciidoctor as well
```